# Poor screen resolution on my HP laptop after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, hp, display-resolution

I bought a HP Laptop 15-da2xxx which comes with a Nvidia GeForce MX130 and a i7-10510U CPU. When trying to change the screen resolution from the settings there is no more than 1366x768 which is bad.

This is what I tried to do but just made it worse, the screen got much smaller with worse quality.

```
cvt 1920 1080
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Comment: Have you selected the option to install third-party drivers, codecs, etc. or installed Nvidia driver after? You have to have done one or the other.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I haven't, but the Nvidia driver seems to be installed after I go in the additional drivers settings, it's using X.OrgXserver

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the specification sheet of your notebook](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06470158), 1366x768 is the best you'll get on your 15.6" screen. If you would like a higher resolution, you will need to use an external monitor, replace the display with a higher-resolution option, or return the machine (if possible) and get one with a higher resolution.